# How to get some data from a json.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
res = JSON.parse(res);
var data = res.body;
```

***res*** is shown as below 
[image]

```
[{"_id":"70:ee:50:13:81:a4",
"place":
{   "location":[113.551302,22.193787],
    "altitude":29,
    "timezone":"Asia/Macau"},
"mark":8,
"measures":
{"02:00:00:13:65:78":
    {"res":
        {"1487682683":[23,76]},
     "type":["temperature","humidity"]},
"70:ee:50:13:81:a4":
    {"res":
        {"1487682691":[1017.1]},
     "type":["pressure"]}},
"modules":["02:00:00:13:65:78"],
"module_types":{"02:00:00:13:65:78":"NAModule1"}}]
```

Question: How can I get **"altitude", "temperature(23)"** e.g. ?

Comment: [Accessing object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) should be one of the first basics to learn.

Comment: `res[0].place.altitude` trye this

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your data model, this is not something I'd do but (with a lot of assumptions) it shows a way to flatten your data and then your answer will be simple.

```js
var res = [{
  "_id": "70:ee:50:13:81:a4",
  "place": {
    "location": [113.551302, 22.193787],
    "altitude": 29,
    "timezone": "Asia/Macau"
  },
  "mark": 8,
  "measures": {
    "02:00:00:13:65:78": {
      "res": {
        "1487682683": [23, 76]
      },
      "type": ["temperature", "humidity"]
    },
    "70:ee:50:13:81:a4": {
      "res": {
        "1487682691": [1017.1]
      },
      "type": ["pressure"]
    }
  },
  "modules": ["02:00:00:13:65:78"],
  "module_types": {
    "02:00:00:13:65:78": "NAModule1"
  }
}]

function flattenMeasures(res) {
  let measures = res.measures
  let flatMeasures = {}
  Object.keys(measures).map(key => {
    let curMeasure = measures[key]
    let curVals = curMeasure.res[Object.keys(curMeasure.res)[0]]
    let curTypes = curMeasure.type
    curTypes.map((type,i)=>flatMeasures[type]=curVals[i])
  })
  res.measures = flatMeasures
  return res
}

console.log(flattenMeasures(res[0]))
```

So basically here is a function that will flatten your complex measures input and store it to `measures` property of an input object. I guess it's not a problem to access them from object formatted in this way.

Comment: umm, thx first. But such as "1487682683" is not a fixed value.. so we cant use the exact value directly..

Comment: Then you need to specify more details about that value. Is it random, is it related to some other data you have, etc. SAme for values like "02:00:00:13:65:78". I mean, we can loop through properties and find it, but would be a vaste of resources to do it just because data is not specified in the question.

Comment: console.log('altitude:',item.place.altitude)
                                 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'altitude' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/gaythree/Desktop/ucla/getpublicdata.js:48:35)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:186:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Comment: I have edited my answer and created a function to flatten your complex `measures` property. It's ES6 syntax with flat arrow functions. Not sure if you need ES5 but shold be able to replace it easily.

Comment: can i have your email ?

Comment: Its not really a good idea to post email here. Also it's not a good idea to resolve questions outside of StackOverflow. Other users cannot benefit from it. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251947/can-i-add-my-email-address-on-a-comment-or-post/251949#251949